# Python How to find top n rows of a group without using pandas

Tags: python-3.x

I have two datasets and need to get top 2 rows of the department with highest salary in Python without using Pandas or dataframes.I have joined two datasets as below but stuck on determining the highest salary.

```
Input1: emp.txt

Depid,Name,salary
1,Peter,100
1,John,200
1,Carlos,150
1,Rick,25
2,Albert,200
3,Mick,300

Input2:dept.txt
Deptid,Dname
1,HR
2,Travel
3,IT

Final result:
1,John,HR,200
1,Carlos,HR,150
2,Albert,Travel,200
3,Mick,IT,300


from collections import defaultdict

data_dict = defaultdict(list)

with open('/content/emp.txt') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        data_dict[line.split(',')[0]].append(line.strip().split(',')[1:])

dat2 = {}
with open('/content/dept.txt') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        dat2[line.split(',')[0]] = line.strip().split(',')[1:]


dd = defaultdict(list)

for d in (data_dict, dat2): 
    for key, value in d.items():
        dd[key].append(value)

for k,v in dd.items():
    for e in v[0]:
        print(','.join((k,*e,v[1][0])))    #join two datasets with nested list items
```

Comment: Use `sorted` to sort the first list, followed by `itertools.groupby` to group by ID, followed by `[:2]`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `csv` module to do some of the parsing for you. After that, a solution close to what you have now falls out as:

```py
import csv
import collections

with open('dept.txt') as file_in:
    departments = {row["Deptid"]: row["Dname"] for row in csv.DictReader(file_in)}

employees_by_department = collections.defaultdict(list)
with open('emp.txt') as file_in:
    for row in csv.DictReader(file_in):
        employees_by_department[row["Depid"]].append(row)

final_result = []
for department_id, department_name in departments.items():
    employees = employees_by_department.get(department_id, [])
    employees = sorted(employees, key=lambda x: int(x["salary"]), reverse=True)
    for employee in employees[:2]:
        employee["Dname"] = department_name
        final_result.append(employee)

print(final_result)

with open('final_result.txt', "w", newline="") as file_out:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file_out, fieldnames=["Depid", "Name", "Dname", "salary"])
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(final_result)
```

You can comment out the `print()` and/or the `writeheader()` depending on if you need the header in the final results.

As is, you should see a printed result of:

```
[
    {'Depid': '1', 'Name': 'John', 'salary': '200', 'Dname': 'HR'},
    {'Depid': '1', 'Name': 'Carlos', 'salary': '150', 'Dname': 'HR'},
    {'Depid': '2', 'Name': 'Albert', 'salary': '200', 'Dname': 'Travel'},
    {'Depid': '3', 'Name': 'Mick', 'salary': '300', 'Dname': 'IT'}
]
```

And a file `final_results.txt` with contents of:

```
Depid,Name,Dname,salary
1,John,HR,200
1,Carlos,HR,150
2,Albert,Travel,200
3,Mick,IT,300
```